# How do I trim transparent borders from my image in an efficient way?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick, imagefilter

I want to automatate the process of trimming transparent edges from PNG images with Node.js, but rather with either with a CLI tool (called by [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)) or a Node module with native bindings than a pure JavaScript implementation for performance reasons.

This sounds like a fairly simple task, but I am searching for weeks without any results that fit my needs.

- The trimming routine should search for transparent pixels, no matter what the input image looks like. Most implementations check the color of the top left pixel.
- The trimming routine should be configurable with a tolerance value, so anything with 20% or less opacity gets removed rather than strictly checking for 0% opacity.

I currently use [Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) and [GraphicsMagick](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) for a complex chain of image manipulations, but because I didn't find a tool for transparency trimming, I wrote a custom [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) plugin that handles the trimming jobs in a rather inefficient way, but it's still working.

Here is an example input image:

[image]

And an expected output image:

[image]

I want to get rid of Jimp though.

Comment: You could write a simple algorithm in C++ and use that as a node plugin possibly?

Comment: @MateuszSowiński Yes, this is what I am going to do if I really don't find anything suitable. I would have preferred not to build my own implementation though, because I would have to learn C++ and node-gyp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/), the image processing library used by sharp, has [`find_trim`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-arithmetic.html#vips-find-trim).

In your case you only want to test the alpha channel (band 3), so extract that and search for the bounding box of values more than 200 from 0 (ie. near solid)::

```
$ vips extract_band test-transparency.png x.png 3
$ vips find_trim x.png --background 0 --threshold 200
0
0
445
475
```

And that's left/top/width/height of the area you want. You can crop that out of your original image with:

```
$ vips crop test-transparency.png y.png 0 0 445 475
```

To make:

[image]

You can do it as a one-liner with:

```
$ vips crop test-transparency.png y.png $(vips extract_band test-transparency.png x.png 3; vips find_trim x.png --background 0 --threshold 200)
```

You can make it a little more efficient in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
left, top, width, height = image[3].find_trim(background=0, threshold=200)
image = image.crop(left, top, width, height)
image.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

And shell out to that. Of course, you might not want to add py as a dependency.